# How to calculate theoretically Output Impedance of a Linear Voltage Regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, impedance, output

I am trying to calculate the output impedance of the following circuit, a linear voltage regulator. What is confusing me is the feedback coming from R1 and R2. 
I used R4= 500 ohms, R3 = 1K , R1= 25k and R2= 23 K.
I hope someone could explain me how should i do it.

Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to know the characteristics of the semiconductors, too.

The basic idea is straightforward. You calculate the voltages and currents throughout the circuit for one operating point. Call the nominal load I<sub>0</sub>, giving an output voltage of V<sub>0</sub>.

Then you draw an additional load, say I<sub>0</sub> + ΔI, and recalculate the numbers, which will yield a different output voltage of V<sub>0</sub> - ΔV.

The ratio ΔV/ΔI is your output impedance.

In rough terms, the change in output current will cause a change in Q1's base current. That in turn will require a change in Q2's collector current, which will affect both the current through the zener diode and Q2's base current. The former will affect the zener voltage slightly, and the latter will affect the voltage drop through the feedback divider. Some of these effects cancel out and some don't.

The easiest way to do this is with a circuit simulator.

Comment: +1 = simulator but nice succint explanation anyway

Comment: I already did that in practice, we call that a measured output impedance value, because we are doing it based on measured values. I was looking for a more theoretical approach of calculation, if i make myself clear.

Comment: I was going to guess R4/Beta. (the current gain.)  (But I'm most likely wrong.)  I agree simulate (or measure) is perhaps least prone to error.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold: That would only be true if the rest of the feedback circuitry weren't there. With it, the current through R4 is more constant than that. But obviously, regulation fails if Q1 needs more base current than R4 can supply. When that happens, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Redraw the circuit, and the approx output impedance is the parallel combination of 3 separate RESISTIVE legs:

[ 1 ]  ro of Q1 (is one leg);  a large value like 100 kΩ
[ 2 ]  boils down to R1 + R2,   formed by R1 + ( R2 || base path of Q2 connects to Rdz ).  Beta Q2 times Rdz is about 500 kΩ
[ 3 ] R3 + Rdz  ~  R3 + 500 Ω
[ FINAL ] ROUT = ro of Q1 || (R1+R2) || (R3+500 Ω)
[ with sample resistor values ] = 100 kΩ || 6 kΩ  || 700 Ω =  ~620 Ω
where R1 = 3 kΩ, R2 = 2.7 kΩ, R3 = 700 Ω, Rdz=5V/10mA  Beta=1000

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the original schematic.  The components most applicable are  R4 connected to the BASE of Q1  and  R1 connected to the EMITTER of Q1. The output current comes from the Q1 EMITTER.

OUTPUT IMPEDANCE is calculated by applying an Ix current "into" the emitter.  And calling the Q1 EMITTER VOLTAGE   Vx.  Then  Vx / Ix  is the Zx (output impedance of this voltage regulator).

Inside the semiconductor GUTS of Q1, the values of interest are:
Vx = Ib ( R4 + rbQ1 + rpiQ1 ).
Ix = Ib (   (B+1) (R1 - 1)  )

so Vx/Ix = (R4 +rb + rpi) / (B+1)(R1-1)

I used VIN = 16 Vdc,  Vout=12 Vdc,  R1=3K,  R4=158
and let rbQ1= 100 ohms,  rpiQ1 = 1500,  BETA = 100.

Zx = 1758/302899 = 5.8 milli ohms
THE OUTPUT IMPEDANCE OF THE VOLTAGE REGULATOR.

Comment: Cesar - Hi, (a) Please stop adding your signature to your posts, as it breaks [this](/help/behavior) site rule, and causes work for other people to remove it again. (b) So that your formula text displays on separate lines, I have forced line breaks where you intended them, by adding 2x space at end-of-line. Remember that 1x Enter does not force a visible line break when displayed on Stack Exchange, which uses Markdown syntax for formatting, even though you see a line break in the "edit box". See more details [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). Thanks.